# radial gradient css issue in ie

Tags: html, css

I have used the following css for radial gradient.

```
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 0 , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), -moz-radial-gradient(50% 100% , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
   background-image:  -ms-linear-radial-gradient(50% 0 , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), -ms-linear-radial-gradient(50% 100% , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
   background-image: -o-linear-radial-gradient(50% 0 , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), -o-linear-radial-gradient(50% 100% , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 0 , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 100% , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
```

It is working fine in firefox and google chrome. I need the same in IE. I have extracted the following css from google to work in IE

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

But i don't know how to change the percentages and colors to match the above css. Any help?

http://jsfiddle.net/tKjap/

Answer (score 0):

Does IE support `rgba` colors? If it does, then just replace the `hex` colors in the copied code with the `rgba` colors.

Ex.)

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)', endColorstr='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Some reading:

- http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/
- http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/

Comment: Hai charlie. I have added my css code i fiddle. Please see my question. I tried bit i could not achieve it. please help.

Comment: I can't teest this as I don't have IE, but the code I posted should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Gradient CSS` as per your requirement and can make also `Gradient CSS` according to your color requirement.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @Champ ya we use this for css gradients :-)

Answer (score 0):

this should help you 
http://davidwalsh.name/css-gradients
http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/gradient-box.html
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: Hai Parag. I have edited my question. Please see and let me know your comments.